# Should i share pipe proxy instance?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have one proxy endpoint `net.pipe://localhost/PipeConsole` and one communication interface.
I have two pieces in program that want to use this interface in different way (call different subset of methods, may intercept)
Should each of them create pipe proxy instance or I should share it?
What if two threads will try to access same pipe proxy method at the same time?

```
ChannelFactory<IManagementConsole> pipeFactory =
            new ChannelFactory<IManagementConsole>(
                new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PipeConsole"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChannelFactory instances are thread safe, so you should be good, i myself share same instance of proxy between multiple threads, and it works fine.